# Problems of having DR as Synchronous Commit

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups, data-synchronization, disaster-recovery, sql-data-sync

In our always on set up we have One Primary and  One Secondary as Synchronous Commit and the DR as asynchronous commit. If i want to change the DR to Synchronous Commit will there be any performance issues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i want to change the DR to Synchronous Commit will there be any performance issues ?

Well, it will take longer to commit transactions, as the primary will wait for the log records to be saved on both sync replicas during each commit.  Whether that causes a "performance issue" depends on the transaction throughput, network bandwidth, distance to the DR location, and the tolerance of the application and users for slower commits.

Comment: In our shop the mangement is deciding to use the DR as the primary for a couple of weeks so that they can do maintenance on the other ones. Due to network lag I guess this wont be a good idea

Comment: You can always switch the DR replica to synchronous, let it catch up, fail over to DR and set the old primary as async.  That's just a failover, not a sync commit DR setup.

Comment: Thanks for the clairification so in a nutshell the recommended availability mode of a DR should be asyn

Comment: Yes DR should normally be async, except while performing a planned failover to DR.